# Is MongoDB $push performance bad (and should I change my data structure)?

Tags: mongodb

I am a MongoDB newbie and working on an application that'll keep lots of logs (~9 million daily).

There are 200,000 devices the app tracks and I was planning to keep the log of each device as (where _id is the deviceID):

```
{
  "_id" : 6,
  "r" : [{
      "t" : 980,
      "dt" : 123432534543543.0
    }, {
      "t" : 980,
      "dt" : 123432534543543.0
    }, {
      "t" : 980,
      "dt" : 123432534543543.0
    }]
}
```

by updating the array with $push (using upsert too).

But, this approach seems to have performance problems (people say, updating the arrays is not a good idea).

Alternatively, I can add each log as a new document like:

```
{
  "monitorID" : 6,
  "t" : 980,
  "d" : 123432534543543.0,
  "_id" : ObjectId("523ff7c0d43023200f000001")
}
```

But, then I'll have to add an index to monitorID and search through millions of logs rather than 200,000. And, keeping data like this sounds like keeping it in MySQL and no advantage of NoSQL.

I'm open to any suggestions to find the best read/write performance. Thx much.

Comment: What is `r`, how much data are you looking at for `r` and how often will it be updated?

Comment: "r" refers to the signals received from devices (t: the kb received, d: timestamp).

A new record is added to "r" each 2-10 minutes (and each record is formed of "t" and "d" for sure, no other items).

Planning to keep 9,000 records in each "r" (there is a 16mb doc. size limit as far as I know)

Comment: Since $push is memory based (it works within the C++ programming as basically appending a new array element) I am unsure if you will see a problem if the document is already in the working set but if you are consistently accessing documents not in the working set then you will see problems with having to load their entirety, not only that but saving a 9,000 element array is probably not too nice either

Comment: "saving a 9,000 element array is probably not too nice either", thinking twice, you are certainly right with that.

I should probably be following the 2nd approach to keep the logs. Thx much..